# Sort by columns in both tables when using "includes" clause in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, join

```
Account.includes(:month_forecasts)
   .where(month_forecasts: { field: :value })
```

I have the above `includes` clause. I have 2 fields `F1` in `Account` table and `F2` in `MonthForecast` table. I need to sort the above result by both these fields.

```
Account.includes(:month_forecasts)
   .where(month_forecasts: { field: :value }).order(:f1)
```

I know the above would sort by `F1` but since `F2` is in the `MonthForecast` table, I am not sure how to sort by that field.

Answer (score 2):

I would use `joins` to make this association, if the association with `month_forecasts` is not for all data, then it will only have the relevant results links. Also leave the fields described in the `order` will help in the next reading.

```
Account.joins(:month_forecasts).where(
    month_forecasts: { field: :value }).order('accounts.f1, month_forecasts.f2')
```

Comment: Based on the OP's comment he wants the `MonthForecast` objects to eager load as well so switching the `joins` to `includes` will solve this

Answer (score 1):

Just use field names as string

```
Account.left_outer_joins(:month_forecasts)
  .where(month_forecasts: { field: :value }).order('f1, month_forecasts.f2')
```

Note, you need to use `left_outer_joins` (or `joins` if you don't want to see accounts without forecasts) instead of `includes` for sorting

UPDATE:

By default it selects only `accounts.*`, but you can add a select with all columns from the second table

```
Account.left_outer_joins(:month_forecasts).select('accounts.*, month_forecasts.*')
  .where(month_forecasts: { field: :value }).order('f1, month_forecasts.f2')
```

Comment: Thanks much for your reply. `left_outer_joins` seems to be picking fields only from the left table. I need all fields from both the tables; how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Biju An outer join with a condition on the joined table is an inner join so `Account.includes(:month_forecasts).where(month_forecasts: { field: :value }) .order('f1, month_forecasts.f2')` is fine.

Comment: *"Note, you need to use left_outer_joins (or joins if you don't want to see accounts without forecasts) instead of includes for sorting"* is incorrect. `includes` with a where condition on the "included" relation creates an "INNER JOIN" and will eager load the relationship data in 1 query